# Brother MFC-J470DW Printer Driver Installation

Tags: printing

Show me how to install the drivers of Brother MFC-J470DW Printer on Linux Ubuntu software. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Visit [[this page]:[1]](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj470dw_us_eu_as)

Choose linux and .deb and click search.

Follow the 3 step process to download the Driver Install tool (at this time it is entitled linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz)

Save the file as shown:

[image: brother1]

Open and extract the tool somewhere convenient (your desktop for example)using Archive Manager.

Open a Terminal (CTRL-ALT-T)

Change to your Desktop directory and make the file executable as follows:

`cd ~/Desktop`

`chmod +x linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1`

run the tool by issuing the command

`sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1`

Answer the questions the tool asks (It starts with your model # as shown below)
[image: brother2]

This approach works with a large number of Brother printers, not just the model you specified.