# No Drivers Found for Brother MFC-J470DW

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, brother

So, I've followed the instructions on Brother's website, I've got the installer and I've tried running it. I've seen this question: [Brother MFC-J470DW Printer Driver Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542388/brother-mfc-j470dw-printer-driver-installation) , and the answer seems to be the exact instructions brother gives me.

Here's the problem: it doesn't recognize my model name as valid.

```
alex@alex-1015E:~/Desktop$ sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 
[sudo] password for alex: 
Input model name ->MFC-J470DW

Driver-packages cannot be found.
 Confirm the model name.
```

I also just tried it with a `O` instead of a `0` in the model name and got the same result. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

As you say [the original post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542388/brother-mfc-j470dw-printer-driver-installation) is not working for you, I have rewrote it as simply as possible, using only the terminal, copy the commands exactly

First download this file in a terminal

```
wget download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
```

Extract it

```
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
```

Run it (Must be root)

```
sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
```

You should see this

```
Input model name ->
```

Make it look like this

```
Input model name ->MFC-J470DW
```

Press enter, now you will see

```
You are going to install following packages.
   mfcj470dwlpr-3.0.0-1.i386.deb
   mfcj470dwcupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb
   brscan4-0.4.3-1.amd64.deb
   brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
OK? [y/N] ->
```

Type Y press enter and same again for the license agreement, now the installer will begin downloading and installing your drivers.

Tested on 14.04 (No printer but driver installation was tested).

Comment: I assumed he just copied what he did, and he had the MFC-J470DN model. He does say that this approach works for many brother printers. It just doesn't make sense to have the model name slightly different from the name written on the printer. Plus I don't want to install the wrong drivers and have to go back and uninstall them later.

Comment: You see in the screenshot `mfcj470dwlpr-3.0.0-1.i386.deb`,  is downloaded, the first part is `mfcj470dw`, this is the driver for your printer. I don't know why it is like that but it is an upvoted answer and shows drivers for you printer printer. If you won't even try it how can you know if it did not work ???

Comment: Tried it using MFC-J470DN and it gave the same error

Comment: You must of done something wrong, both, versions let me download the driver, here you can see in my terminal, http://i.imgur.com/r8oPGdg.png  both N and W models are available for download, I don't know what went wrong for you but I will write a new tutorial, just copy/paste the commands

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.  Your steps were very clear.

I downloaded the zip file from their website, then followed your steps to make execcubatle and run the installer.

The brother website has the driver, but the steps are faulty for ubuntu 12

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj985dw_us_eu_as

Comment: This is not an answer. You can post a new question with your specific problems.

Comment: Please modify your post to present it more like an answer to the OP :).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is common across linux distros.  The driver package is looking for a case-sensitive specific model name for the printer.  I have the MFC-j5910DW and needed to type in the printer name exactly like that with the j and DW in this exact case.  The printer packaging did display the printer name in that matter.

Comment: This is more of a follow on comment